# Boost Array documentation reference?

Tags: arrays, boost

Where can I find a reference for Boost Array. This page:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/array/reference.html

does NOT reference some features I know to exist, such as the `size` function. Where is a definitive reference? Do I have to use the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tricky -- you have to click on "class array" in the header text.  That brings you to this page:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/array.html

Which should have everything you're expecting to find :)

Comment: There it is! I've used it for so long that I've guessed at half of those things! Nice to finally have the reference. Thanks.